# Global scope variable showing "Unresolved reference"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
import json
import os
from botocore.vendored import requests
from custom_validator import CustomValidator

dev_mode = 'DEV' in os.environ
access_token = None

if dev_mode:
    import test_config as config
else:
    import config as config

def myfunc(data):
     if not (access_token):
         .....
```

But inside of `myfunc`, I get the `Unresolved reference` error when trying to use `access_token`.
Even if I put `global` before it in the initialization above, I get:

> Global variable 'access_token' is undefined in the module level

I'm kind of confused - why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Using Python 3.6.

Comment: Please post the entire error message including stack trace.

Comment: That's everything.. i get that in PyCharm.

Comment: Code is correct, check what is inside imports, especially `config`

Comment: This is happening because of Python's LEGB variable scoping rules (https://stackoverflow.com/a/293097/4180458). You need to use `global access_token`  statement before if condition. In order to access/modify a global variable inside a function, you need to tell Python that it's a global variable else it will raise an error `local variable 'access_token' referenced before assignment` or create a local variable (in case of assignment).